# how to login with pop up ask for user and password batch file

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, batch-file, vbscript, twilio

Im trying to make a batch file or vbs file to download a .csv file but when i get to the website it has a popup!!(different window) that is asking to log in with user and password then i must hit the "OK"  button. how do i tell the batch file to jump to the pop up and log in with the user name and password?

i found this code vbs code. but it get stuck on the pop up. and i must do it manually.

VBS CODE:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxx9/Calls.csv?PageSize=1000"
  IE.Visible = True

  While IE.Busy
    WScript.Sleep 50
  Wend


Set ipf = IE.document.all.UserNamer
ipf.Value ="MYUSERNAME"
Set ipf = IE.document.all.Password
ipf.Value ="MYpassword"
Set ipf = IE.document.all.submit
ipf.Click
IE.Quit
```

`

### And tried

```
  Set args = WScript.Arguments

 '// you can get url via parameter like line below
 '//Url = args.Item(0)

  Url = "https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACfcxxxxxxxxx059/Calls.csv?       PageSize=1000"
 dim xHttp: Set xHttp = createobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
 dim bStrm: Set bStrm = createobject("Adodb.Stream")
 xHttp.Open "GET", Url, False
 xHttp.Send

  with bStrm
    .type = 1 '//binary
    .open
    .write xHttp.responseBody
    .savetofile "C:\Users\jeff\Downloads"
  end with
```

Whats the best why i can automatically download this file?

THIS IS THE WORKING FILE.

```
'GetRemoteBinaryFile.vbs
CSVFile = "Calls.csv"
DestFolder = "C:\Downloads"

URL = "www.itworks.com"
bstrUser= username
bstrPassword=password
Set xml = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
xml.Open "GET", URL, False,bstrUser,bstrPassword
xml.Send

set oStream = createobject("Adodb.Stream")
Const adTypeBinary = 1
Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
Const adSaveCreateNotExist = 1 

oStream.type = adTypeBinary
oStream.open
oStream.write xml.responseBody

' Do not overwrite an existing file
oStream.savetofile "Calls.csv", adSaveCreateNotExist

' Use this form to overwrite a file if it already exists
' oStream.savetofile DestFolder & ImageFile, adSaveCreateOverWrite

oStream.close

set oStream = nothing
Set xml = Nothing
```

Comment: In your second example try `xHttp.Open "GET", Url, False, bstrUser, bstrPassword` with `url="that from 1st example"`

Comment: start firefox https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxx9/Calls.csv      is working but need to jump to the next window to hit the ok button to download. sooo close!! how do i make it jump to the next window? something lile " getwindow "

Comment: i tried using the xHttp.Open "GET", Url, False, bstrUser, bstrPassword us said with the first url didnt work.

Comment: maybe i put the code wrong.. xHttp.Open "GET", Url, False, bstrUser, bstrPassword           ( do i put user and password in the bstr(USERNAME) and bstr (Password)?

Comment: Assign variables `bstrUser` and `bstrPassword` with real Username and Password as `bstrUser="UserName"` and `bstrPassword="Password"` or simply use `xHttp.Open "GET", Url, False, "UserName", "Password"`

Comment: Works but i can get to click to "ok" button NOW. how do i jump to the pop up and click ok

Comment: OK got it to finally work. THANK YOU!! JosefZ. used different code, but using the   bstrUser="UserName" and bstrPassword="Password"  with the    xHttp.Open "GET", Url, False, bstrUser, bstrPassword and used the       oStream.savetofile "Calls.csv", adSaveCreateNotExist